# openapi springboot - Error 'swaggerWelcome' threw exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, springdoc-openapi-ui

i use  the dependency of org.springdoc,  see below in y spring boot project

```
       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have this error , can i have help ?

```
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'indexPageTransformer' defined in class path resource [org/springdoc/webmvc/ui/SwaggerConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'indexPageTransformer' parameter 3; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'swaggerWelcome' defined in class path resource [org/springdoc/webmvc/ui/SwaggerConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springdoc.webmvc.ui.SwaggerWelcomeWebMvc]: Factory method 'swaggerWelcome' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/http/HttpStatusCode
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]

    ... 50 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springdoc.webmvc.ui.SwaggerWelcomeWebMvc]: Factory method 'swaggerWelcome' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/http/HttpStatusCode
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 64 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/http/HttpStatusCode
```

I try to change the version of springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui, but always same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What version of Spring Boot do you use? I got the same problem when I tried to use openapi 2.0.0 and Spring Boot 2.7. Then I found out that this version of openapi needs Spring Boot verion 3 and above.

Please try to update the Spring Boot dependencies version (I assume you're using the spring-boot-starter-web) and the Spring Boot version to be 3.0.0 or above.

Here's some topic I found https://170.106.8.194/repo/jhipster/jhipster-lite/issues/4351